# Can I enter Kenya and Tanzania multiple times on single-entry visas?

Tags: visas, africa, kenya, tanzania

I will be traveling to Kenya and Tanzania, and will make multiple stops in each country: Home -> Kenya -> Tanzania -> Kenya -> Zanzibar (Tanzania) -> Kenya -> Home. I will not travel outside of those two countries.

I've read and heard conflicting reports for whether or not I will need a *single-entry* or *multiple-entry* visa for each country. Some websites state that a single entry is fine as long as I stay in the East African community (Kenya, Tanzania, and other countries), e.g.:

> Tanzania single-entry tourist visa validity: up to three months. You can re-enter Tanzania on the same visa (providing it is still valid) if coming into Tanzania for a second time from Kenya, Uganda, Rwanda or Burundi.

While this says I can enter a **second** time, it does not mention a third entry. Some consulate representatives have told me a single-entry visa is fine, some have told me a single-entry visa will not work since I will enter a third time.

Do I need to apply for a multiple-entry visa to Kenya and Tanzania, or will a single-entry visa suffice?

Comment: Nairobi Int'l Airport](https://www.nairobi-airport.com/visa_on_arrival_kenya.php) says there's an East Africa visa, but it doesn't cover Tanzania and costs as much as a general multiple entry visa.

Comment: Unless there is a significant cost difference, it seems to me that the safe bet is going with the multi-entry visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ended up using the single-entry visa for all of our entries into the East Africa community countries. The immigration officer when we arrived at Nairobi airport confirmed that a single-entry visa was sufficient.

For our particular case, getting a multi-entry visa was significantly more complicated than a single-entry one.

Answer (score 3):

You can Enter Tanzania Multiple times as long as your Visa is still valid. This is however not a guarantee of Entry.This is because of security reasons and other issues.

Although Tanzania is a member in the East African Block, it is not part of the  Multiple Entry East African Tourist Visa costing $100 per person. This Visa is for Uganda ,Kenya and Rwanda. If you Intend to visit Kenya first then acquire the Kenyan Visa first.

If your to visit Tanzania and any other member states of the other East African community, you will need Visas for both Tanzania and the other country you intend to visit.

Comment: So if the OP's visa is for Tanzania, the answer is actually "maybe."

Comment: If he has a visa for Tanzania the he /she must acquire that of Kenya.

Comment: I forgot the OP wanted to go to Kenya as well. OTOH, the Answer does assert that the OP may not even be successful in entering Tanzania.